# Python -- sizing frames with weights

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In the minimum example code below, you can change the last range(), currently at 3, to 6 and notice that the frames with buttons all get smaller than if you run it with 3.  I have configured 6 columns of "lower_frame" to all be weight 1.  The expected result is that there are 6 empty columns of the same width no matter how many buttons I put in there.  If I put 3 buttons in there, as the example below has by default, the buttons are quite large and leave only room for about 1 more button.  If I put 6 buttons in, they fill the space and each gets smaller.

How do I achieve the expected result of having equal width columns no matter how many widgets I actually put in the cells?  The goal here is a standard size to these buttons that is based on proportion of the screen, not a pixel size, and have it always be the same no matter the number of buttons.  I realize I could do a bunch of math with bounding boxes and programatically set the sizes at runtime, but that seems like overkill and lacking elegance.

Minimum example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

mods = {}
modBtns = {}

root = tk.Tk()
upper_frame = ttk.Frame(master=root)
lower_frame = ttk.Frame(master=root)
right_frame = ttk.Frame(master=root)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=5)

for i in range(6):
    lower_frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(5):
    lower_frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

upper_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
lower_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
right_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

for i in range(3):
    mods[i] = ttk.Frame(master=lower_frame)
    mods[i].columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mods[i].rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    modBtns[i] = ttk.Button(master=mods[i], text="mod{0}".format(i))
    modBtns[i].grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
    mods[i].grid(column=i, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

root.geometry("700x700+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I realize the example isn't quite as minimum as it could be, I was just trying to mirror my actual project's layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the rows and all of the columns to have the same width/height, you can set the `uniform` attribute of each row and column. All columns with the same `uniform` value will be the same width, and all rows with the same `uniform` value will be the same height.

Note: the actual value to the `uniform` attribute is irrelevant, as long as it is consistent.

```
for i in range(6):
    lower_frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='whatever')
for i in range(5):
    lower_frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='whatever')
```